# Get page properties image with typoscript in typo3 6.x

Tags: typoscript, typo3-6.1.x, typo3-6.2.x, typoscript2

I'm created a plugin to extends the page and the page properties and generate a fileupload/imageupload. Its upload the images, save it in the database and equals the db records with the page media upload in resources.

When I upload a image in the media (resources), I can call it with

```
lib.headerimage = IMAGE
lib.headerimage {
file {
  import.data = levelmedia:-1, slide
  treatIdAsReference = 1
  import.listNum = 0 }}
```

The field in the properties call `media` - with `levelmedia:-1,slide` i get a Image.

My field calls `menuimage`, and when I try `levelmenuimage:-1,slide` or `menuimages:-1,slide` or `menuimages`, `levelmenuimages` its not work.

So what I must write in the import.data to get my image field from the page properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 import.data = levelfield:-1, menuimage, slide
```

because levelmedia is a predefined value inside TYPO3 to find it recursively by media field in page properties. but if you want to recursively access an other field there's "levelfield:-1" for.

Comment: Add some explanation of what and why you've changed.